# Text to Number (Redshift)

Tags: sql, text, casting, amazon-redshift, numeric

The field that I am using comes in as type: text and I want to convert it to a number with 2 decimal places. For some reason the following convert it to a number but also rounds it:

```
"UNIT_PRICE"::numeric

"UNIT_PRICE"::decimal
```

both convert a 0.65000000000000 text value to 1 but I would like to get a numeric 0.65

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: FYI numeric and decimal are synonyms.Have you tried specifying the scale & precision?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a cast function with as a decimal to get only 2 decimals back.

```
SELECT CAST(0.65000000000000 AS DECIMAL(10, 2))
```

More information about casting as decimal can be found here: [SQL Server CAST() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_cast.asp)

Answer (score 1):

In Redshift the default precision and scale are 18 and 0 - DECIMAL(18,0).  This is whole numbers.  If you want a different scale you need to specify it.  DECIMAL(18,2).

See: [Numeric types - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Numeric_types201.html)

Answer (score 0):

using trunc function:

```
select trunc("UNIT_PRICE"::numeric,2) ;
```